# Python & D3.js Dashboard Crossfilter Heat Map

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, heatmap, crossfilter

I've successfully replicated this interactive dashboard map [example](http://adilmoujahid.com//posts/2016/08/interactive-data-visualization-geospatial-d3-dc-leaflet-python/) here.

I now want to input my own data. My python is more simple than the example's since all my data is already structured in the way I want it. 
Here's my python:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import json


data_path = './input/'

def get_location(longitude, latitude, ny_json):

    point = Point(longitude, latitude)

    for record in ny_json['features']:
        polygon = shape(record['geometry'])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            return record['properties']['Name']
    return 'other'

with open(data_path + '/geojson/ny_HA.json') as data_file:
    ny_json = json.load(data_file)

app = Flask(__name__)
    #route to html index
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

    #route data
@app.route("/data")
def get_data():
    df = pd.read_csv(data_path + 'Mikes_NY_geocoded_tickets.csv', sep=';')

    df['location'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_location(row['longitude'], row['latitude'], ny_json), axis=1)

    cols_to_keep = ['timestamp', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'Violation', 'Type', 'DayOfWeek', 'location']

    #remove NaN values 
    df_clean = df[cols_to_keep].dropna()
    #return a json
    return df_clean.to_json(orient='records')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Here is my data `geocoded_data.csv`:
[image: data]

When I run my app `python app.py`, No errors and when I enter the localhost into my browser my dashboard appears, but everything is empty, my cross filters and map.

Here's what the browser is displaying:

[image: My_Dashboard]

Here are my errors in the browser console[image]
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Gordon apologies for the late response, please see the edits ive made to my question.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to guess what is going wrong without seeing the running application. But it sure looks like the front end is expecting a timestamp field that's not there. I'd use `console.log` to print the data received by the front end in the browser console, and see if it has the expected format.

Comment: @Gordon, I'm Sorry, after looking at my python I realized I'm not communicating any of my column data or my location data to my java script :/

Let me make some corrections, then I'll edit my post.

Comment: No problem, this is likely one of those questions that will get answered in the process of refining the question. Just trying to offer some tips so you can nail it yourself. :-)

Comment: @Gordon Thanks! Okay so I've revised my post. I made edits to my python to read in the data. It seems the error is coming from my `js`. For some reason its not liking that `.setMinutes(0)` is null. My timestamp data is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`. Any idea why the error?

Comment: @Gordon, So its definitely the `timestamp`. I marked out `//d["timestamp"].setMinutes(0);` `//d["timestamp"].setSeconds(0);` and the whole map properly displayed with all crossfilters working, except for the time crossfilter. - Hope this helps a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've shown your JS code (in the debugger screenshot above), it's pretty easy to guess what is going wrong.

You have

```
d["timestamp"] = dateFormat.parse(d["timestamp"]);
d["timestamp"].setMinutes(0); // Error: d["timestamp"] is null
```

Here's the [documentation for d3.time.format.parse()](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#parse):

> Parses the specified string, returning the corresponding date object. If the parsing fails, returns `null`. Unlike "natural language" date parsers (including JavaScript's built-in parse), this method is strict: if the specified string does not exactly match the associated format specifier, this method returns `null`. For example, if the associated format is the full ISO 8601 string `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`, then the string `"2011-07-01T19:15:28Z"` will be parsed correctly, but `"2011-07-01T19:15:28"`, `"2011-07-01 19:15:28"` and `"2011-07-01"` will return `null`, despite being valid 8601 dates.

You haven't shown what the value of `d["timestamp"]` is prior to conversion, but chances are that there is a subtle difference between the expected format and the actual format.

In particular, if the screenshot of your data is correct, there are no seconds in your date format, but your `d3.time.format` specifier is expecting them?

Comment: You Sir are an absolute wizard. Thank you so much, that was the issue. In my csv my timestamp was formatted %m/%d/%Y, but in my JS I had it formatted %Y-%d-%m! THANK YOU again!